# Вытащить текст из html в php

Tags: php, html

Доброго времени суток.
Стоит такая задача: вытащить текст из *html* в *php*.

```
<button type="submit" id="btnmessage" class="btn btn-primary send">Отправить форму</button>
```

На сайте есть несколько кнопок вызова формы и текст в кнопке, в данном случае: "***Отправить форму***" динамически изменяется, в зависимости от того, на какую из них нажал пользователь. Например если пользователь нажал на кнопку с текстом "***Заказать звонок***", то вызывается форма и в кнопку из примера передаётся текст "***Заказать звонок***", заменяя тем самым текст "***Отправить форму***". 
Т.е. просто переписать строчку из примера в php не выйдет, нужно достать текст, который на данный момент в кнопке.
Текст нужен дальнейшей обработки и отправки в письме на почту.

Comment: domDocument и, возможно, domXpath

Comment: Если формы всплывают в лайтбоксе, то такое лучше делать на js

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понял нужно ловить текст в уже в обработчике, соответственно можно так добавить в button атрибут value

```
<button type="submit" id="btnmessage" class="btn btn-primary send" value="Отправить форму" name="submittype">Отправить форму</button>
```

а в php уже вытягивать value как из обычного элемента формы к примеру

```
$_POST['submittype']
```

таким образом можете добавлять сколько угодно кнопок отправки формы с разными value и по ним уже делать определенную обработку

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" id="btnmessage" class="btn btn-primary send" value="Заказать звонок" name="submittype">Заказать звонок</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btnmessage" class="btn btn-primary send" value="Отправить форму" name="submittype">Отправить форму</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ, данный ранее верный, но моё мнение что лучше будет просто изменять средствами js value кнопки. Добавьте value в кнопку. И уберите submit.

```
function setMessage(message){$("#btnmessage").val(message); form.submit(); /*имя формы добавьте за место Form */}
```

И далее добавьте событие на каждую кнопку при клике на которую будет происходить запись `onClick = setMessage("заказать звонок")`

А потом как и в прошлом ответе отлавливайте значение через `$_POST` для своих целей